# Check status of AWS job

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

When I upload a file to s3 bucket a event is triggered and a AWS batch job is started. Is there any way to check the status of AWS batch job in my java code. I have to perform some operation when the status of AWS batch job is SUCCEEDED.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the choice of using the ListJobs / DescribeJobs APIs to poll for status.

> ListJobsResult listJobs(ListJobsRequest listJobsRequest) Returns a
> list of AWS Batch jobs.
>
> You must specify only one of the following items:
>
> - A job queue ID to return a list of jobs in that job queue
> - A multi-node parallel job ID to return a list of that job's nodes
> - An array job ID to return a list of that job's children
>
> You can filter the results by job status with the jobStatus parameter.
> If you don't specify a status, only RUNNING jobs are returned.

Or you can listen for the CloudWatch Events which are emitted as jobs transition from one state to another if you prefer an event-driven architecture.

[ListJobsRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/batch/AWSBatch.html#listJobs-com.amazonaws.services.batch.model.ListJobsRequest-)

Comment: thanks, is there way to continuslouly check job status until its status changes to SUCCEEDED.

Answer (score 0):

For solving this problem, I have created separate thread callable thread where looped until status of Job is SUCCEDED and FAILED. Extracted the job status based on job id using describe job API.

```
class ReturnJobStatus implements Callable<String>
{
public String Callable()
{
   while(!(jobStatus.equals("SUCCEEDED") || (jobStatus.equals("FAILED")))
   {
     // extracts job status using describeJob API after passing jobId
     Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000);
   }
  return jobStatus;
}
```